# Swift: Unable to addConstraint to ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am adding an UberLogo on my app's menu bar using ImageView. However, the logo is paned towards the upper left corner of the cell. I tried to re-center it to its containing cell using an online video. The addConstraintWithFormat is working but not the add Constraint. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```swift
class MenuCell: BaseCell {

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "UberLogo")
        return iv
    }()


    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(28)]|", views: imageView)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: You should activate your adding constraints: 
 
let ns = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
ns.isActive = true;

Comment: Actually `H:|[v0(28)]|` is not right, because you're saying two contradictory things: "pin me on both side" and "make my width exactly 28". You can't have both, because what if the sides are 100 pixels apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the addConstraint documentation:

> When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s isActive property to true instead of calling the addConstraint(_:) method directly. The isActive property automatically adds and removes the constraint from the correct view.

Additionally, NSLayoutConstraint has the following function:

```
class func activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])
```

Try activating your constraints like this and see if it helps:

```
addSubview(imageView)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28),
  imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28),
  imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
  imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
])
```